# How does LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER really work?

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, android-gps

I see that `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER.getLastKnownLocation()` returns the last location, but how is the location updated? If the GPS is disabled, will it entirely rely on BSSIDs detected by WiFi? What if the WiFi is also disabled? Does it take mobile service tower data into account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the location service has basically three levels: GPS, WiFi, Cell tower.

GPS is used with the `GPS_PROVIDER`, and WiFi and cell tower go both into the `NETWORK_PROVIDER` bucket.

To quote the [`NETWORK_PROVIDER` description](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#NETWORK_PROVIDER):

> This provider determines location based on availability of **cell tower** and **WiFi access points**. Results are retrieved by means of a network lookup.

Comment: How does it actually work internally? Does it make a request to Google (Map API?) for each `getLastKnownLocation()` call? If it's Map's API, does each call cost?

Comment: `getLastKnownLocation()` doesn't do any request, since the position is already known. But if you want to get a new up-to-date location, it sends the WiFi MAC address or the [mobile cell ID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_ID) to Google to resolve its location.

Comment: I see. In that case, would `requestLocationUpdates()` need to be called followed by `getLastKnownLocation()`?

Comment: Well, if you use `requestLocationUpdates()` you'll get a new location from the LocationListener anyway, so no need to use `getLastKnownLocation()` directly afterwards (it would just return the same location again).